# MySQL validate Text using triggers

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table it have Raiting(condition,discription)
condition must be

- superb, excellent, good, fair, poor damaged

---

how to validate this using mysql triggers

Comment: what if validation fails ?

Comment: BEGIN
declare msg varchar(255);
 declare var varchar(255);
 set var=new.conditions;
 
   if var !='excellent' or var !='excellent' then
   set msg=concat('MyTriggerError:Raiting Conditions must be Superb,Excellent,Good,Fair or Damaged');
     signal SQLSTATE '45000' set message_text = msg;
end if;

END      i use this but it not working

Comment: Awesome description - "it not working". Full of information. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way than using triggers is to either use a foreign key relationship or enumerated types.  I would suggest creating a table of valid ratings that take on those six values.  You can then define a foreign key relationship when using the rating for columns in other tables.  Much simpler than maintaining a trigger.  Plus, it gives you the opportunity to keep additional information about each rating, such as a short abbreviation or a more detailed abbreviation.

Comment: i try to do this tanks for help